# Extract depth map from a 3D anaglyph image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, stereoscopy

Suppose we have a generic red/cyan 3D anaglyph photo. How can it be processed so a depth map is extracted?

Answer (score 4):

An anaglyph is just a superposition of a left-eye and right-eye image, using different colours for each.

Assuming you can use the colour components to extract the original greyscale left and right images, the problem is no different to any stereo vision problem. You need to determine the epipolar geometry, perform rectification on one of the images, then create a disparity map to derive relative depth information.